# X-Code:Generate documentation comments like in Eclipse (/**)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, code-documentation

I'm using X-Code since 2 months. I have my low and highs as I do need to search for certain features I'm used to from other IDE's.

Now I do have a question about documenting the code.

From developing Java in Eclipse, I'm used to autogenerate the doc comment for a method with(/** + Enter) apparently, this doesn't work in X-Code. Is there a similar way, or do I have to write the whole comment block myself?

Thanks for a quick input.

Cheers

Comment: I don't know of an automatic way but creating your own code snippet and saving it in the Xcode library is possible.  See documentation on "Creating a Custom Code Snippet".